# Debian Packaging Dependencies Checking

Tags: package-management, dependencies, debian

How to force a debian package to check some dependency installed?

Comment: What do you mean by "to check some dependency installed"? Normally, when installing debian package, with the use of dpkg, it already checks dependencies of that specific package, whether it is needed to be installed or already installed on the system.

If you want to install a package and ensure that that package will be installed IF AND ONLY IF dependencies were satisfied, add "--no-force-all" to dpkg (ie. dpkg --no-force-all -i package.deb).

Comment: Thanks CamicriSystems for your answer, But the title is "Debian Packaging" that deliver my means which is about Debian Packaging Configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you list dependencies in the Debian/control file.

See https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-binarydeps

Comment: I read it, but I need a straightforward help.
In your provided link, I think doesn't matter how to check for UNINSTALL a package during check for dependencies.
Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you need help, post your configuration file (the control file) and a detailed description of the problem or question. Simply stating something is broken does not help us to help you.

Comment: Thanks in advanced man.
I'll be ask it in another Q, because I think you put the correct answer for my semi-question now.
Appreciate it.